# Worklight 6.1 Not connecting to Production server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I applied the latest Worklight 6.1.0.2 fixes, but the Mobile Apps continue to try and connect to Development server and not the Production server specified in the Build and Deploy Target settings. The client is making a request to an adapter that is installed on the server. I have confirmed this with Wireshark and set initOptions on startup to capture the IP address.  I have Worklight 6.1 EE edition installed and have applied the patches there as well.  It is like the app ignores the production server.

Does anyone have any suggestions other than upgrading to 6.2?

Can this be a Development Studio problem with eclipse plugin issue?

Comment: Did you rebuild your project? right-click the project folder, run as>Build all Environments. Then check to make sure that your worklight properties are correct (android: worklight.properties and iphone: worklight.plist) check to make sure that the wlServerHost and wlServerPort is your production server.

Comment: Yes - rebuilt, cleaned project.  No android, focusing on IPad - so in the plist the production host and port are correct.  There is a  / on the end of context name which has come up in some blogs.

Answer (score 0):

After you change the remote server protocol/host/port/context properties in *Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target*, you should execute *Run As > Build All Environment* and not *Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server*.

- By executing *Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server*, the connection values in wlclient.properties/worklight.plist will be the ones for the local development server settings.
- By executing *Run As > Build All Environment*, the connection values wlclient.properties/worklight.plist will be the ones set in the Build Settings and Deploy Target.

Additionally:

- In 6.1, if after a Build All Environments, you will then select Run As > Xcode project for example, the local development connection values will be used... So make sure not to do that.
- In 6.2, if you do the above action (Run As > Xcode project (or any other external IDE option provided)), if you have remote server properties set up - they will be used. If you do not have any remote server properties set up, the local development connection properties will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that this is working now.  Eclipse is sometimes slow in activating the build process, and I was incorrectly pushing the run on Development Server, which might be over writing the values.  If I wait patiently, the build cycle will generate the client that connects properly.

Thanks for the help.